# Passing elements in an array to hiera lookup as keys

Tags: puppet

I am getting an error when trying to execute my puppet module:

```
Error 400 on SERVER: certificatefqdn is not a hash or array when accessing it with certificatefile
```

This is what my `hiera` file looks like:

```
testmodule::install::certificates:
  test1.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate1.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass1'
  test2.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate2.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass2'
  test3.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate3.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass3'
```

The `init.pp` in my module looks like this:

```
class testmodule (
  $certificates = hiera('testmodule::install::certificates'), 
 )
{
    $domains = [
      test1.domain.com',
      test2.domain.com',
      test3.domain.com',
    [

  testmodule::install { $domains:
    certificates => $certificates,
  }
}
```

The `install.pp` in my module looks like this:

```
define testmodule::install ($certificates)

    {
       $domain = $name
       $certificatefqdn = $certificates["$domain"]
       $certificatefile = $certificatefqdn['certificatefile']
       $certificatepass = $certificatefqdn['certificatepass']
       notify{"This is the certificate file: $certificatefile" :}
    }
```

I'm expecting to see an output like this for each of the elements in the domain array:

```
Notice: This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt
Notice: /Stage[main]/Testmodule/Testmodule::Install[certificate2.crt]/Notify[This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt'
```

Instead I see this:

```
Notice: This is the certificate file: test2.domain.com['certificatefile']
Notice: /Stage[main]/Testmodule/Testmodule::Install[test2.domain.com]/Notify[This is the certificate file: test2.domain.com['certificatefile']]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is the certificate file: test2.domain.com['certificatefile']'
```

How can I correctly access the keys in the nested hash in hiera using the elements in domains as the initial key?

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be correct already.

I have set this up according to your question:

1/

```
# manifests/init.pp
class test (
  $certificates = hiera('test::install::certificates'), 
) {
  $domains = [
    'test1.domain.com',
    'test2.domain.com',
    'test3.domain.com',
  ]

  test::install { $domains:
    certificates =>  $certificates,
  }
}
```

2/

```
# manifests/install.pp 
define test::install ($certificates) {
  $domain = $name
  $certificatefqdn = $certificates["$domain"]
  $certificatefile = $certificatefqdn['certificatefile']
  $certificatepass = $certificatefqdn['certificatepass']
  notify{"This is the certificate file: $certificatefile" :}
}
```

3/

```
# spec/fixtures/hiera/data/common.yaml 
---
test::install::certificates:
  test1.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate1.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass1'
  test2.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate2.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass2'
  test3.domain.com:
    certificatefile: 'certificate3.crt'
    certificatepass: 'testpass3'
```

4/

```
# spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml 
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "All levels"
    paths:
    - common.yaml
```

Compile and apply:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --modulepath spec/fixtures/modules --hiera_config spec/fixtures/hiera/hiera.yaml -e 'include test'
Warning: The function 'hiera' is deprecated in favor of using 'lookup'. See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.3/reference/deprecated_language.html
   (file & line not available)
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.14 seconds
Notice: This is the certificate file: certificate1.crt
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Test::Install[test1.domain.com]/Notify[This is the certificate file: certificate1.crt]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is the certificate file: certificate1.crt'
Notice: This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Test::Install[test2.domain.com]/Notify[This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is the certificate file: certificate2.crt'
Notice: This is the certificate file: certificate3.crt
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Test::Install[test3.domain.com]/Notify[This is the certificate file: certificate3.crt]/message: defined 'message' as 'This is the certificate file: certificate3.crt'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
```

So I can't reproduce this.